# How can I direct my output to screen and to file simultaneously?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell

- Linux, (Ubuntu) here.
- Should be effective every time I open a new terminal.
- Output to file should contain all messages including errors and warnings, should be the same as shown in the screen.

Can I achieve this by changing the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Take a look: `man script`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's a tool, `screen`, that's usually used for persistent sessions, which has the ability to log console output to a file. Setting it to run immediately upon login is [described here](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3908651/Make-GNU-Screen-Your-Default-Shell.htm). The option for output logging is `-L`. `screen` has a lot of other console and session related features. [The user manual is over here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).